# Should the verb "help" be followed by another verb at infinitive or gerund?

Tags: gerunds, infinitives

Given the sentence

> My father helped me [doing/do] my homework.

I had learned that the preposition "*to*" can optionally follow the verb "*help*". However, the solution to my exercise says that the above sentence should correctly be:

> My father helped me doing my homework.

Instead of:

> My father helped me do my homework.

Could someone please explain to me why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My father helped me do my homework.

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/help), **to** is indeed optional with an infinitie after **help**, so this sentence is correct. As a native English speaker, I would say that it is informal to omit the **to**.

> My father helped me doing my homework.

There is no reference to using **help** with a gerund or participle **doing**, and it certainly does not sound natural to me.

The only other possibility that would sound natural is:

> My father helped me **with** my homework.

Answer (score 0):

Should the verb “help” be followed by another verb at infinitive or gerund? What about this sentence:

> Did you help developing this project?

Would that be correct / sound natural to a native speaker?

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Please don't post new questions as answers. Ask a new question by clicking the [Ask Question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button.