# What one is correct to use? "Do you want to help me to build?" or "Do you want to help me build?"

Tags: grammar, phrases

**What one is correct to use?**
"*Do you want to help me to build?*"
**or**
"*Do you want to help me build?*"

*I don't know what one to use*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Help to do something or help do something?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47221/help-to-do-something-or-help-do-something) Also [Should the verb “help” be followed by another verb at infinitive or gerund?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/124293/) and [help you do OR to do something - difference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27560/) and [“help robot population TO adapt” — can I omit “to”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/134525/), among others.

Comment: @FumbleFingers , yes, thanks!